# $X$ a topological space. If $A$ lies inside a closed set. Does it follow that the closure of $A$ also lies inside this closed set?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> PROBLEM: $X$ a topological space. If $A$ lies inside a closed set. Does it follow that the closure of $A$ also lies inside this closed set?

MY TRY:

Suppose $A \subseteq F$ where $F$ is closed set. I want to show $\overline{A} \subseteq F $. Take aribtrary $x \in \overline{A} $. So $x$ is limit point of $A$. In particular, can find a nghbd $N$ of $x$ such that $N \cap A \neq \varnothing $.

IF $ x \in A$, then we are done since then we would have $x \in F$. Suppose $x \notin A $. Then either $x \in F \setminus A $ or $x \in X \setminus F$.

If $x \in F \setminus A \implies X \in F $

If $ x \in X \setminus F \implies x $ cannot be a limit point of $A$

Therefore, $\overline{A} \subseteq F $.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Complexity of proof partially depends on what you start from. But you can show what you want without reference to points. Recall that A set $A$ is closed iff $\bar{A}=A$. Then use this and monotonicity of closure operation.

Comment: @DonAselmo: How do you define the closure? Because a possible definition is to say that the closure is the smallest closed set containing the initial set; in this case, the result is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it for what it is worth, I would argue something along the lines of:

Say $A \subseteq C$ some closed set.
$$\overline{A} = \bigcap_{A\subseteq F} F, \text{ $F$ closed in $X$.}$$

If $x \in \overline{A}$ then
$$x\in\bigcap_{A\subseteq F} F, \text{ $F$ closed in $X$}$$
and in particular, $C$ is a closed set of $X$ that contains $A$, and so as $x$ in all such sets, $x \in C$ and so $\overline{A}\subseteq C$.